# Does pthread_cond_wait() acquire the mutex immediately after being signalled?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have a thread, A, whose function runs in a loop, does something and wakes another thread, B, up. Then it releases the mutex and goes on with next iteration. Thread B waits until being signalled, then does something. My question is, Is it guaranteed that B will acquire the mutex after being signalled or can thread A re-acquire the mutex before B, in the next iteration of the loop?

```cpp
pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t signal = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

int condition=0;

//function for thread A
void func_A(void *arg){
    while(1) {
      pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
      do_something();
      condition=1;
      pthread_cond_signal(&signal);
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    }
}

//function for thread B
void func_B(void *arg) {
    while(1) {
      pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
      while(condition = 0)
        pthread_cond_wait(&signal, &lock);
      do_something_else();
      condition=0;
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make sure B acquires the mutex after it is signalled?

Comment: You have no guarantee that the mutex will get acquired by another thread. If your algorithm can rapidly keep using the mutex, then depending on computer architecture, it might hog it. Have a resource limit like memory or a semaphore count and when it hits a limit, stop running until that resource is available again. That will give others a chance to get the mutex.

Comment: Or even better, use a multithreading design that doesn't care. Like a queue. Especially good is one that can run lock-free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I overcame this problem by using a semaphore which is initialized to 1. Thread A performs a `sem_wait()` operation on the semaphore, before locking the mutex `lock`. Thread B performs a `sem_post()` operation on the semaphore, before relasing the mutex `lock`.

```cpp
pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t signal = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

sem_t my_sem; //properly initialized with value set to 1

int condition=0;

//function for thread A
void func_A(void *arg){
    while(1) {
      sem_wait(&my_sem);  //notice the change
      pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
      do_something();
      condition=1;
      pthread_cond_signal(&signal);
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    }
}

//function for thread B
void func_B(void *arg) {
    while(1) {
      pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
      while(condition = 0)
        pthread_cond_wait(&signal, &lock);
      do_something_else();
      condition=0;
      sem_post(&my_sem);  //notice the change
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to make sure B acquires the mutex after it is signalled?

No, there is no such way - `B` will compete with other threads for owning the mutex, as usual.

Also, how do expect `B` to automatically acquires mutex on being signaled, when `A` owns the mutex at the time it signals?